# Adding Checkbox to comboBox not visible in dropdown

Tags: c#, windows, forms, checkbox, combobox

I am adding a checkbox to a comboBox in a windowsform. The checkbox add and I can select them as Items but I can see the text of the box to tick. In the combobox drop down the items are list empty and clicking on them specific the correct details when incepting the selected item.

How do I make them visable to see the box and name?

Comment: Put your code!!!

Comment: //Create a new checkbox
                                    var comJect = new CheckBox();

                                    //Defining the checkbox property
                                    comJect.Name = headItem;
                                    comJect.Text = headItem;
                                    this.Controls.Add(comJect);
                                    dllMethodParameters.Controls.Add(comJect);
                                    dllMethodParameters.Items.Add(comJect);

Comment: dllMethodParameters.Controls.Add(comJect[Depth]); 
This statement adds the checkbox to the control but not the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own user control. First step is to create subclass the `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class CheckComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        public CheckComboBox()
        {
            this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        }
    }
}
```

You should set the DrawMode property to tell the ComboBox that we intend to render the drop-down list items ourselves. The next step was to define a class to contain our drop-down list item data and maintain the state. This is a simple class:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class CheckComboBoxItem
    {
        public CheckComboBoxItem(string text, bool initialCheckState)
        {
            _checkState = initialCheckState;
            _text = text;
        }

        private bool _checkState = false;
        public bool CheckState
        {
            get { return _checkState; }
            set { _checkState = value; }
        }

        private string _text = "";
        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { _text = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Select Options";
        }
    }
}
```

After that go back to your `CheckComboBox.cs` and add delegates `DrawItem` and `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class CheckComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        public event EventHandler CheckStateChanged;

        public CheckComboBox()
        {
            this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            this.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(CheckComboBox_DrawItem);
            this.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(CheckComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }

        void CheckComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Index == -1)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!(Items[e.Index] is CheckComboBoxItem))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(
                Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                this.Font,
                Brushes.Black,
                new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
                return;
            }

            CheckComboBoxItem box = (CheckComboBoxItem)Items[e.Index];

            CheckBoxRenderer.RenderMatchingApplicationState = true;
            CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(
            e.Graphics,
            new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y),
            e.Bounds,
            box.Text,
            this.Font,
            (e.State & DrawItemState.Focus) == 0,
            box.CheckState ? CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal :
                CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
        }

        void CheckComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckComboBoxItem item = (CheckComboBoxItem)SelectedItem;
            item.CheckState = !item.CheckState;
            CheckStateChanged?.Invoke(item, e);
        }
    }
}
```

In DrawItems delegate, the first thing we do is to verify that the item we are rendering was added as a CheckComboBoxItem. If it is not, we render it as a simple string. Otherwise, we get the appropriate CheckComboBoxItem from the Items collection (using the DrawItemEventArgs.Index property). Then we call the CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox() method, passing in the Graphics object, into which we want to render the CheckBox, and the location, size, text, font, focus and check states.
The second one allows us to toggle the check box in the drop-downs, but doesn't allow the user of this control to know that anything has happened. So we also add a public event to notify the control's users of a change to the check state of an item in the drop-down list:

```
public event EventHandler CheckStateChanged;
```

Finally, if you want to use this control, in the default Form1 of your application type this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            checkComboBox1.Items.Add(new CheckComboBoxItem("One", true));
            checkComboBox1.Items.Add(new CheckComboBoxItem("Two", true));
            checkComboBox1.Items.Add(new CheckComboBoxItem("Three", true));

            this.checkComboBox1.CheckStateChanged += new EventHandler(this.checkComboBox1_CheckStateChanged);
        }

        private void checkComboBox1_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is CheckComboBoxItem)
            {
                CheckComboBoxItem item = (CheckComboBoxItem)sender;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

You have so many links that can be useful to you. You do not put any code so we don't know what exactly you need...

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18929/An-OwnerDraw-ComboBox-with-CheckBoxes-in-the-Drop

Thank you @Rob and @Mamun for correcting me.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)